# How do i use a value from a function in another as a callback? Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I´ve been making a prototype of webservice and I get confronted with the following problem: Whenever I try to use a 'var' as a callback i get: undefined.

What I'm tryng to do is:

```
var mysqlquery = function (){
   var vAlue = XXX;
}
var service = function (pp, ee, cb){
 var toReturn= ({                      //XML code
     Value: vAlue
     })
cb(toReturn);
};
```

Output should be XXX

The service runs fine and logs the values, but when i try to make it a callback to respond it is undefined, I guess because of the async of node.
Already tried making it a global or global.window or calling it inside another function, none of wich work. I don´t want to use extra modules for this, is there any method for it ? (Also tried this.)
Any tip is much apreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why did you put `;` after `function()`???

Comment: What does the line `var vAlue = [0].field;` mean? Are you missing the name of the array?

Comment: There, edited, is it understandable now ?

Comment: `vAlue` is only available in the scope of `mysqlquery`, not inside `service`. If you want to use it, you have to `return` it.

Comment: You also have to actually call `mysqlquery`.

Comment: "vAlue is only available in the scope of mysqlquery" > This much I know.
"If you want to use it, you have to return it" > This much I don´t.
Could you explain me how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know that defining a `var` in a function limits its scope to that function, but you can pass that data out of the function using a `return`, like so:

```
var mysqlquery = function (){
   return 'XXX';
}

console.log(mysqlquery())
> "XXX"
```

What's happening in the `console.log` line is that your function is being evaluated, and returns "XXX", and *then* it is passed to console.log.

This is the foundation of callbacks: if you have an asynchronous function, you can pass a callback function into it to feed in the result of the async function:

```
function print(res) {
  console.log(res)
}

function asyncThing(cb) {
  var ten = 5 + 5
  window.setTimeout(cb.bind(this, ten), 5000)
}

asyncThing(print)
... [wait five seconds]...
> 10
```

Comment: I'm only describing the concept– I don't have enough of your original code to provide a functioning response. If you describe what you're trying to do some more, I can give more advice.

Comment: Well, i have to make the function  sync and wait because the return is set after the response is sent, i will work on it, thanks for the help.
Can't upvote because i dont have enough rep yet.

Comment: Yeah, async functions get tricky, and there are different ways to return the value you want depending on what you're trying to do. If you like reading documentation, you can try [Promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/)

Comment: I´ve been burning my eyelashes with that for the past 3 hours, but still i can´t figure out how to implement it.